# how a hive UDF runs when a sql is running?

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

I'm confused about the execution of Hive UDFs in SQL. 
The nodes get JARs from HiveServer when an SQL compiles into an MR job? If some static variables are declared in UDF, where these static variables exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is right. Hive basically makes these jars available across all its nodes by adding it to distributed cache as `add Jar`.
You have to register the UDF such that hive recognizes it. Registering a UDF will make an entry into the hive metastore. This is usually done by doing something like `CREATE FUNCTION <function_name> AS org.apache...`
This should usually be available in hive-env.sh

Comment: should the jars be placed to ${HIVE_HOME}/auxlib/ ? If not, It will raise exceptions like classNotFound during mapper when the sql lead to MR jobs.

Comment: And If some static variables are declared in UDF, where these static variables exist?